# how to smooth a hand-drawn line with Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics2d

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286808/issues-creating-a-pen-tool-with-javas-path2d) code to implement a freehand drawing tool in Java and Graphics2D. So I have a Path2D made up of a lot points. Is there an algorithm to smooth this line? I don't mean anti-aliasing, I mean something like converting the path to a path of bezier curves. Something like [this](http://www.12inchpianist.com/line-smoothing-in-java), but with a Path2D as input. I would think this a recurring problem but I couldn't really find something useful.

Comment: I was thinking after I posted my question I could maybe use the PathIterator for the algorithm I linked to. Will try later when I'm home.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found what I needed at: http://javagraphics.blogspot.com/2010/06/shapes-implementing-freehand-pencil.html

Edit: and since I now know the exact term for this problem (curve fitting) I can google it better and also found this post: [Java curve fitting library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878200/java-curve-fitting-library)

Edit: also look at http://johnsogg.blogspot.com/2010/01/cardinal-splines-and-catmull-rom.html

Comment: I accepted my own answer, couldn't do it immediately though, SO forces you to wait 4 hours.